# Python/Pandas Calculate the mean time (hour) of a Datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, average, mean

I have a Pandas DataFrame (data) with a column `['Date']` in DateTime (date and time) which represents the time of arrival.

**How to calculate the mean of only the time of the day, (not date) and get a time in Hours, Minutes, Seconds?**

I tried:
`data['Time'] = data['Date'].dt.time`

And then calculate `data['Time'].mean()` but it shows: " `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'` "

The sample of my data:

```
    Date
35  2021-12-02 09:03:00
36  2021-12-01 08:57:00
37  2021-11-30 08:50:00
38  2021-11-29 08:40:00
39  2021-11-28 10:31:00
41  2021-11-25 08:58:00
43  2021-11-23 08:37:00
44  2021-11-22 08:56:00
45  2021-11-19 09:00:00
46  2021-11-18 09:30:00
47  2021-11-17 08:47:00
48  2021-11-16 08:45:00
49  2021-11-15 09:44:00
```

Comment: Could you share a sample of your data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
data['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(data['Date'].dt.time.astype(str))

import datetime
out = data['Time'].mean()
print (out)
0 days 09:06:00

time = (datetime.datetime.min + out).time()
print (time)
09:06:00
```